# onClick function remove :hover pseudo class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I stole a little jQuery script to make navigation links on the same page scroll smoothly and made minor changes.

It works fine so far, but when a link is clicked, the CSS for the hover event is not removed and the text is still underlined. Now I think that has got to do with the preventDefault function which does what it's name suggests and prevents the default behaviour.

How can I remove the hover pseudo class after the mouse leaves links again?

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('a.smooth').click( function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': ($target.offset().top - 100)
        }, 900, 'swing', function ()
        {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**
I just discovered the problem - I had `a:active` set to `text-decoration: underline`.
See my fiddle for reference:  **http://jsfiddle.net/2zcNt/**

Sorry, that was by far too obvious. I guess I need some sleep.

Comment: Think we'll ned the HTML & CSS As well. JSfiddle please?

Comment: "but when a link is clicked, the CSS for the hover event is not removed" Could you replicates this behaviour on jsFiddle?

Comment: The `hover` pseudo class shouldn't be affected by this code. Provide a fiddle so we can take a look.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` is not for changing CSS. If you need to remove the underline do this with CSS.

Comment: Try this. In your html `<a class="smooth hoverClass"/>link</a>` and in css `.hoverClass:hover { text-decoration: underline;}  .smooth { text-decoration: none; }` and in your js shown above after `e.preventDefault()` line type `$(this).removeClass('hoverClass')`. Not sure if this answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the style for the `:visited` pseudo class is underlined. You can change this with:

```
a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

EDIT:

After you posted the JSFiddle, I can see the problem is actually with the fact you're embedding the h1 inside the anchor. You should embed the anchor tags inside the headers.

Edited [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zcNt/1/). Notice the CSS is as it was before.

Comment: Almost. It was a:active ;-)

Comment: That's what I initially put! But then I saw you mention after the mouse leaves the element, so it confused me. Active only applies while the element is being clicked.